# How do I learn the stochastic calculus of Poisson processes?

Tags: reference-request, poisson-process

I'm looking for references on the stochastic calculus of Poisson processes. My books tend to focus on derivative pricing, where Brownian motion reigns supreme. Maybe some jump-diffusion models thrown in in chapter 10, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I'd like to read a book that covers the Ito calculus of Poisson processes with random intensity and jump sizes, in a detailed way like all the derivatives books present Ito calculus. (Stochastic control would be a plus, but isn't necessary)

Comment: I found the book by Cont and Tankov "Financial Modelling with Jump Processes" very useful.

Comment: A Chapter by Nicolas Privault gives a brief introduction to the Stochastic Calculus of Jump Processes http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf

Comment: The last chapter of Shreve's second volume is a good start.

Comment: As mentioned by Gordon, chapter 11 of Shreve's II volume (_Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous Time Models_), called "_Introduction to Jump Processes_" is a good starting point. Then, as mentioned by LocalVolatility, Cont and Tankov's book is an option if you want to dig further into the subject.

Comment: @LocalVolatility, thank you this seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @noob2: I've read Privault's notes and I think they're great. It doesn't go into enough depth, however

Comment: @Gordon: I tried to exclude Shreve in my question, but I guess I should've written chapter 11 ;)

Comment: Another good one, IMHO, is chapters 8-11 of the book "mathematical methods for financial market" by Jeanblanc et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the suggestions in comments:

Nicolas Privault's chapter  Stochastic Calculus of Jump Processes [available online] provides only a very brief overview.

Chapter 11 of Shreve's II volume (Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous Time Models), called "Introduction to Jump Processes" is a good starting point. Then  Cont and Tankov "Financial Modelling with Jump Processes" provides more material, with an entire volume on the subject.

Another suggestion was chapters 8-11 of the book "mathematical methods for financial markets" by Jeanblanc et al.

Contributors were @LocalVolatility, @Gordon, @user357269, @DaneelOlivaw